# designing classification problem of weather data

Tags: machine-learning, data-modeling, classification, regression

In normal 2 or multi class classification problem, we can use any famous machine learning algorithm like Naive Bayes or SVM to train and test the model.
My problem is that I have been given weather data where the label variable is in the format of "20 % rain, 80 % dry" or "30% cloudy, 70% rain" etc. 
How should I approach this problem? Will I need to covert the problem into regression somehow? In that case, if there are three labels (rain, dry, cloudy) in data, **what may be the right approach to convert percentage information to continuous values?**
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a neural network with three outputs labels Rain, Dry, Cloud.

If you have data with label "20 % rain" then weight of instance will be 0.2. If the are no "rain" label should contain "false". Other approach is to 3 different regression classifier with same converting convention. I think regression would work better.

Neural networks will  be good choice because it can do all three regression/classification at once and they can influence on each other. Additionally the training algorithm is straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the expressions "20 % rain, 80 % dry" and "30% cloudy, 70% rain" represent probabilities, that the classes are mutually exclusive and that we may ignore a possible ordinal relationship (such as "dry > cloudy > rain") among them, models such as polychotomous logistic regression may be fit to these values, as though they were grouped or replicated.

I suppose other, *ad hoc* procedures could be employed as well, which would minimize, for example, the Kullback–Leibler divergence.