# Scikit-learn Multiclass Naive Bayes with probabilities for y

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, document-classification

I'm doing a tweet classification, where each tweet can belong to one of few classes.
The training set output is given as the probability for belonging that sample to each class.
Eg: tweet#1 : C1-0.6, C2-0.4, C3-0.0 (C1,C2,C3 being classes)

I'm planning to use a Naive Bayes classifier using Scikit-learn. I couldn't find a fit method in naive_bayes.py which takes probability for each class for training. 
I need a classifier which accepts output probability for each class for the training set.
(ie: y.shape = [n_samples, n_classes])

How can I process my data set to apply a NaiveBayes classifier?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What to use for multi-class probability label data and same type prediction in sklearn?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170191/what-to-use-for-multi-class-probability-label-data-and-same-type-prediction-in-s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not so easy, as the "classes probability" can have many interpretations.

In case of NB classifier and sklearn the easiest procedure I see is:

1. Split (duplicate) your training samples according to the following rule:
   given (x, [p1, p2, ..., pk ]) sample (where pi is probability for ith class) create artificial training samples:
   (x, 1, p1), (x, 2, p2), ..., (x, k, pk). So you get k new observations, each "attached" to one class, and pi is treated as a **sample weight**, which NB (in sklearn) accepts.
2. Train your NB with `fit(X,Y,sample_weights)` (where `X` is a matrix of your `x` observations, `Y` is a matrix of classes from previous step, and `sample_weights` is a matrix of pi from the previous step.

For example if your training set consists of two points:

- ( [0 1], [0.6 0.4] )
- ( [1 3], [0.1 0.9] )

You transform them to:

- ( [0 1], 1, 0.6)
- ( [0 1], 2, 0.4)
- ( [1 3], 1, 0.1)
- ( [1 3], 2, 0.9)

and train NB with

- `X = [ [0 1], [0 1], [1 3], [1 3] ]`
- `Y = [ 1, 2, 1, 2 ]`
- `sample_weights = [ 0.6 0.4 0.1 0.9 ]`

Comment: But now , with your new classifier, you get several answers for every training example. How do you combine them?

Comment: You did not understand the concept, there is still **one** classifier, only training data changed. You do not "combine" anything - simply traing NB on something that looks "inconsistent" - but it does not matter, it will learn correctly.

Comment: Still don't get it. Your predictor will return 4 values. How do you combine them for the two examples your are interested it?

Comment: Naive Bayes returns probabilities for each class, not "just some values", so by basic Bayesian thinking you choose the class with the biggest probability, so you take argmax of this "output vector". Still in my example we get **two** values, not four - I don't know where did you get this number from.

Comment: Proposed method is just a training set transformation, which does not change the problem's dimensionality. It was the R^2->{1,2} classification problem before the transformation and is after. The only difference is that each training point has been altered and duplicated. It is still R^2->{1,2} problem, solved with NB. X is the **set** of training points, not **one** training point. And Y is a set of responses in N, not one response in N^4.

Comment: @MartinBöschen Instead of attributing each test case to a particular label, they are associated with a confidence of belonging to each label. Refer this as an example [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055112/designing-classification-problem-of-weather-data?rq=1)